# How to plot an RMA in R

Tags: r, plot

I need help I am not good with R but I need to use it..

I did a model II regression and the results are Ok:

Regression results

Method       Intercept     Slope Angle (degrees) P-perm (1-tailed)

1    OLS      41.00237     0.7954845        38.50171              0.02

2     MA      39.32632     0.8013633        38.70741              0.02

3    SMA       38.85986   0.8029994        38.76444                NA

4    RMA       39.03664    0.8023793        38.74284              0.02

but I don't know how to plot the RMA results..can somebody help me?

Lidia

Comment: From the output, it seems you've used "lmodel2" package? If you look at the examples of `?lmodel2`, there is a reference to plotting RMA like `plot(my_regressions_results, method = "RMA")`. Perhaps, this is what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes and I feel really an idiot….Thank you!